# Using Cmder in Windows Terminal

Tags: cmder, windows-terminal

I just wondering can I integrate Cmder with Windows Terminal since I have successfully add Cmder to Windows Terminal but when I open it on Windows Terminal, It would pop-out a Cmder window instead of integration with Windows Terminal.  Is there any idea or feature about how to integrate?
 [i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqL6K.png)

Comment: I don't think I've seen this functionality. I believe part of the draw is that it is not the windows terminal and just does everything but better. You might be better contacting a maintainer / opening an issue.

Comment: No. Cmder is just an implementation of conemu, which is a terminal app itself. Windows terminal is terminal app just like Cmder / Conemu. You can have different "shells" in either one, but it's one or the other. If Windows terminal is missing a feature of Cmder, you should put in a request.

Comment: **Official documentation for Cmder + Windows Terminal:** https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-Windows-Terminal-Integration

Answer (score 9):

The answer is yes.

First create bat file:cmd_init.bat:

```
@echo off
set CMDER_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder
set CMDER_START=C:\

"%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\init.bat"
```

then add new setting in terminal setting file:

```
{
                "acrylicOpacity": 1, 
                "closeOnExit": true,
                "colorScheme": "JetBrains Darcula", 
                "commandline": "cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\cmder\\vendor\\cmd_init.bat\"", 
                "cursorColor": "#00FF00", 
                "cursorShape": "vintage", 
                "fontFace": "Fira Code Medium", 
                "fontSize": 11, 
                "guid": "{f15b60f6-b700-472a-8b2f-d79c7bd4b9a5}", 
                "historySize": 9001, 
                "icon": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\cmder\\icons\\cmder_green.ico", 
                "name": "Cmder", 
                "padding": "10, 10, 10, 10", 
                "snapOnInput": false, 
                "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%", 
                "useAcrylic": false
            }
```

Done,this is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above 2 steps and then follow this for the rest

```
{
        "name": "Dracula",
        "cursorColor": "#F8F8F2",
        "selectionBackground": "#44475A",
        "background": "#282A36",
        "foreground": "#F8F8F2",
        "black": "#21222C",
        "blue": "#BD93F9",
        "cyan": "#8BE9FD",
        "green": "#50FA7B",
        "purple": "#FF79C6",
        "red": "#FF5555",
        "white": "#F8F8F2",
        "yellow": "#F1FA8C",
        "brightBlack": "#6272A4",
        "brightBlue": "#D6ACFF",
        "brightCyan": "#A4FFFF",
        "brightGreen": "#69FF94",
        "brightPurple": "#FF92DF",
        "brightRed": "#FF6E6E",
        "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
        "brightYellow": "#FFFFA5"
}
```